# How to change the size of tkinter objects according to the display resolution

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi I made the GUI of this program in `1980x1080` and everything is fit to the window, but when I run the program on the other pc of resolution `1366x768` 3/4 of the GUI is outside the display.

This is my constructor for the GUI

```
class Main:
    def __init__(self,master = None):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry(str(master.winfo_screenwidth())+'x' +str(master.winfo_screenheight()))
        self.master.state('zoomed')
        
        self.variables_for_graphs()
        self.variables_for_inputer()
        self.variables_for_graphs_menu()
        self.place_frames()
```

screenshot of the program in `1980x1080` display resolution:
[image: screenshot of the program in 1980x1080 display resolution]

screenshot of the program in `1366x768` display resolution:
[image: screenshot of the program in 1366x768 display resolution]

I add scaling to the constructor

```
dpi = master.winfo_fpixels('1i')
factor = dpi / 72
master.tk.call('tk', 'scaling', factor)
```

it did not help

if anything else is need please comment

Answer (score 0):

you can multiply every dimension in your GUI by the ratio between the current resolution and the original resolution, but that would result in very ugly look, instead of manually setting the sizes of each object you should let tkinter size your objects.

for grid layout (similar to yours) you have. [Tk Geometry manager](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html)

```py
widget1.grid(row=0,column=0,rowspan=2,sticky="NWSE")
widget2.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="NWSE")
widget3.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky="NWSE")
parent_widget.rowconfigure((0,1),weight=1,minsize=200)
parent_widget.columnconfigure((0,1),weight=1,minsize=200)
```

to set your widgets to grow to fill all its master space, with a minimum size of 400x400.

for widgets that you `pack` you should use

```py
widget.pack(expand=True,fill="both")
```

which will also make the child grow to fill its parent space, the size system may look intimidating at first, but once you start using it you can get any shape you want with it that scales the way you want.

avoid using `place` as you have to manually manage its size (unless you have an object that must be of fixed size and position like a logo or floating widget), and avoid filling numbers for sizes yourself, things that you can fill yourself are probably padding, buttons size (sometimes), and font size (under different dpi), you should have tkinter manage other dimensions in your GUI otherwise your GUI won't scale well.